# When using ui-select with theme Bootstrap: how to make the select smaller?

Tags: ui-select, angular-ui-select

When using ui-select with theme Bootstrap, the "select" looks the same size of a Bootstrap button, ie: `btn btn-default`

I want the select to look like a "`btn-sm`" button.

How can I do that? what classes should I modify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution someone gave in the Github site of ui-select:

Wrap the directive in a div with `form-group-sm`, eg:

`<div class='form-group-sm'><ui-select>...</ui-select></div>`

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/169#issuecomment-298361767